# aggregation condition in case when

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset with a structure similar to the one bellow

```
fruit, value
apple, 234
apple, 2341
pear, 3233
grape, 323
pear, 3234
grap 1234
```

I am trying to find a count of a range of the numbers that are in the bottom 10% of the range by performing a query like the one below. (the ultimate goal of the query is to calculate and see the ranges of the calc go up in increments of 10%) I also have a group by clause so I would like the counts to be grouped by the fruit and aggregated that way. Bellow is the query I have tried

```
select fruit, count(case when (value <= (((max(value) - min(value)) * .1) + min(value))) then 1 end)
from fruit_juice
group by substring(fruit, 5, 5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate the table in the `from` clause to get the limits you want.  `Join` those results back to your query and use those values for the query:

```
select substring(fj.fruit, 5, 5),
       sum(fj.value <= fmm.minv + (fmm.maxv - fmm.minv) * 0.1)
from fruit_juice fj join
     (select substring(fruit, 5, 5) as fruit5,
             max(value) as maxv, min(value) as minv
      from fruit_juice
      group by substring(fruit, 5, 5)
     ) fmm
     on fmm.fruit5 = substring(fj.fruit, 5, 5)
group by substring(fruit, 5, 5);
```

Note that your `group by` expressions should match the expressions in the `select` clause.

EDIT:

I'm not sure where the `substring()` is coming from in your question, so this version removes it:

```
select fj.fruit, sum(fj.value <= fmm.minv + (fmm.maxv - fmm.minv) * 0.1)
from fruit_juice fj join
     (select fruit,
             max(value) as maxv, min(value) as minv
      from fruit_juice
      group by fruit
     ) fmm
     on fmm.fruit = fj.fruit
group by fruit;
```

Comment: sorry correct the substring was something I forgot to take out

Comment: Could you take it a step further so I can understand and show me how to do the count for 10 and 20 percent. Also why do you have a sum clause in the select statement? shouldnt it be a count?

Comment: you can also not sum bool values so I do not think what you have works

Comment: @user2524994 . . . Your question is tagged MySQL and you can sum boolean expressions in MySQL.  In other databases, I would use a `case` instead, but I used this because the tag is quite explicit.